# Property [x] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I experience this problem when I query the database using a set of conditions. if the conditions are found in the database results are displayed but if they are not found it throws the error:

> Property [room_no] does not exist on this collection instance.

I am trying to query my database hotel where room status is vacant and room type is as the user has specified. I have tried searching similar problems in this platform but non seem to fit my area of problem.

I have tried to use `get()`, `first()` but non solves my problem.

My function to check available rooms:

```
public function availablerooms(Request $request)
{
    try {
            $customers = Customer::All();
            $room_type = $request->input('room_type');
            $room = Room
                        ::All()
                        ->where('room_status', 'Vacant')
                        ->where('room_type', $room_type);

            return view('admin.availablerooms')
                       ->with('room', $room)
                       ->with('customers', $customers);
    }
    catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
    {
          //    
    }

}
```

my code to display data:

```html
@if(count($room) > 0)
        @foreach($room->all() as$room)

            <tr>
                <td>{{$room->id}}</td><td>{{$room->room_no}}</td><td>{{$room->room_type}}</td><td>{{$room->room_status}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button  type="button" onclick="set()" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
                            Checkin
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach
        @else
        <div>
            <p class="text-warning"> No records found with that criteria </p>
        </div>
    @endif

    </tbody>
```

I expect that if records are found it displays(which it does) if not found it shows no records available.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are aliasing the current item in your foreach loop as `$room`, which is the same name as your collection.

In your controller you should change the `$room` variable name to `$rooms`.

```php
$rooms = Room::where('room_status', 'Vacant')
    ->where('room_type', $room_type)
    ->get();

return view(...)->with('rooms', $rooms);
```

Now in your view you can do the following:

```php
@foreach($rooms as $room)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $room->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $room->room_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ $room->room_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $room->room_status }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" onclick="set()" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    Checkin
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this sentence:

```php
$rooms = Room
    ::All() // <---
    ->where('room_status', 'Vacant')
    ->where('room_type', $room_type);
```

When you execute the `all()` method you are retrieving all the records on your `rooms` table (so you are executing the query there). Basically a `select *` query, so at this point you retrieve a collection of elements that matches this condition (this is: a collection of **all** the `Room` objects).

What follows -as your code suggests- is that you are constraining the results with the `where()` method, but notice that given that you already have a collection instance returnetd, this constraining is done at a **collection** level and not at a **database** level.

What happens when you do a `where()` clauses and the collection doens't have an object that matches the condition? It will return an `empty` collection. This is:

```php
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3444
     all: [],
   }
```

So this means that it will never throw the exception that you specified in your try-catch clause (`ModelNotFoundException`) even if no model is found. So then, when you return your results to your view.

How to solve it: Well you could execute the query after you specify the where clauses so those are executed at a database level then throw the error. Another option is use your existing setup and then count your returning collection and throw the exception manually. I'll give you the response for the first option:

```php
$rooms = Room
    ::where('room_status', 'Vacant')
    ->where('room_type', $room_type);
    ->get();   // <---- here we execute the query.
```

So how could you throw the error if no model is found?

```php
if( ! $rooms->count())
{
    throw new ModelNotFoundException();
}
```

For the second option just:

```php
if( ! $rooms->count())
{
    throw new ModelNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: still not working. If a user searches for lets say deluxe rooms that are vacant as of the project now , if there exists such a record there will be an output but if there is no vacant deluxe room it throws the property[] not found error.

Comment: @dxdenitoraymars but where is the error thrown? What file/line? If not model found you should throw the exception as I mentioned in my answer (check the `if ( ! $rooms->count()){ ... }` clause.